# supply a function with a string or an int

Tags: c++, string, int

I have a function (see below) which outputs the origanal input variable. The problem is I cannot have....

```
int print(std::string value){
    std::cout << value << std::endl;
return 0;   
}
```

if I try to give an int, it throws an error. I need a way to be able to feed it any variable type (later check what type it is) and act accordingly

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I completely rewrote this because I misread the question...

You can use templates to create a generic function:

```
template <class T>
int print(const T& value)
{
    std::cout << value << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Or you can simply have two different functions:

```
int print(const std::string& value)
{
    std::cout << value << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

int print(int value)
{
    std::cout << value << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Still gives an error when using print(2);

invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'std::string&' from a temporary of type 'int'

Comment: I rewrote my answer, please see again.